# I am not able to see or use cut/paste in lion

Tags: macos

I upgraded to lion on the day it was released. After that I updated my system twice even then I am not able to see any cut paste option as specified [here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/29/cut-and-paste-mac-os-x-lion/).

[image]

Mine is still:-[image]

Note: Command+Option+V  is not working for me. Nothing happens :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to press the Option key BEFORE clicking Edit on the Menu. This will dynamically change the menu to show the "move" option.

Comment: No need to press Option *before* selecting the menu. The menu commands change dynamically if you press Option while the menu is already open.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have tried (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>), as sometimes it will not show in the edit menu, try a P-RAM reset on the computer. Turn your computer off, then turn on while holding <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, the computer will turn off and on, wait for four charms before releasing. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.